# D3.js selection.data() optional parameters

Tags: d3.js

Per D3 v4 [documentation](http://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bdata), function syntax for `data()` is given as `selection.data([data[, key]])`.

This suggests to me `data` AND `key` are optional parameters for `data()`.  But wouldn't `data` always be a required parameter?  I know `key` is optional and defaults to the array index if not specified - but why would the `data` parameter ever be optional, what is the point of binding nothing to DOM elements?

Comment: Im sorry but that's not correct. The data parameter is optional. "If data is not specified, this method returns the array of data for the selected elements." https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_data

Comment: Did someone delete comments on this?  The reason it's written `[data[, key]]` is because first, data is optional (see @EricGuan comments).  Second, when data is specified then key becomes optional.

Comment: @Mark Yes, two users deleted comments.  Your comment is the best thus far.  If you post as an answer, I'll select it as "answer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All arguments to `.data` are optional.  From the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_data):

> If data is not specified, this method returns the array of data for
>   the selected elements.

Further, it is written as `[data[, key]]` because *when data is specified* `key` then becomes an optional parameter.